# 'System.NullReferenceException' occurs when generate Chanal Uri In Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Whenever I am trying to create push notification in windows phone 7 and windows phone 8, my code is working fine but whenever I tried to build same code on windows phone 8.1, it's showing 'System.NullReferenceException' Occur when generate Chanal Uri In Windows Phone 8.1.

Code is given below :

```
            String channelUri="XYZ";
            HttpNotificationChannel myPushChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find(channelUri);
            if (null == myPushChannel)
            {

                    myPushChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel(channelUri);
                    myPushChannel.Open();
                    myPushChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(myPushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);
                    myPushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(myPushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
                    myPushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(myPushChannel_ErrorOccurred);
                    myPushChannel.HttpNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<HttpNotificationEventArgs>(myPushChannel_HttpNotificationReceived);
                    myPushChannel.BindToShellTile();
                    myPushChannel.BindToShellToast();
                    uri = myPushChannel.ChannelUri;
            }
            else
            {

                if (myPushChannel != null)
                {
                    myPushChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(myPushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);
                    myPushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(myPushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
                    myPushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(myPushChannel_ErrorOccurred);
                    myPushChannel.HttpNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<HttpNotificationEventArgs>(myPushChannel_HttpNotificationReceived);
                    uri = myPushChannel.ChannelUri;
                    if (!myPushChannel.IsShellToastBound)
                        myPushChannel.BindToShellToast();
                        if (!myPushChannel.IsShellTileBound)
                        myPushChannel.BindToShellTile();
                }

            }
        }
```

Everything is working fine in windows phone 7/8 but not working on windows phone 8.1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Voting to close again as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about WP8.1 Universal Apps, and not silverlight, you should use line below to obtain PushNotificationChannel:

```
PushNotificationChannel channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();
```